# Queries in "log_queries_not_using_indexes" do actually use an index

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I enabled the `log_queries_not_using_indexes` option in MySQL to try to eliminate a few queries that don't use indexes to improve overall performance and have less I/O on disc.

This is an example from the logfile:

```
# User@Host: xxx[xxx] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 97  Schema: xxx  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000822  Lock_time: 0.000103  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1495617184;
SELECT term_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_termmeta
WHERE term_id IN (130,202,230,...)
ORDER BY meta_id ASC;
```

So I think it misses an index on either `meta_id` or `term_id`.

**But both columns do have an index and - the table is empty anyways.**

[image]

So why does this query appear in the logfile and what can I actually improve?

Comment: You have discovered one of the reasons why I recommend turning off `log_queries_not_using_indexes`.

Comment: @RickJames Generally it soundslike a super useful option but the output just doesn't make quite sense to me :-/

Comment: "Not making sense" is one of the reasons for not turning it on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since the table is empty, the exercise to optimize the query now might be useless, the execution plans will change when the table is populated sufficiently.

Secondly, to see how exactly optimizer chooses to execute the query, you can either run

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT term_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_termmeta
WHERE term_id IN (130,202,230,...)
ORDER BY meta_id ASC;
```

or, if you are running MariaDB 10.x, set `log_slow_verbosity='query_plan,explain'` (`GLOBAL` or `SESSION` value, depending on how you execute the query).

If you run explain, you will see the plan right away. If you set the verbosity, you will see it in the slow log along with the problematic query next time when it appears there.

Most likely the plan will show that `possible_keys` contains `term_id`, but `key` is actually `PRIMARY`. If so, it will mean that optimizer chose not to use `term_id` for finding rows (probably because it's not worth without the data), but to use `PRIMARY` for sorting. Since `log_queries_not_using_indexes` actually means showing queries which don't use indexes *for lookups*, it explains why the query ends up in the log.

When/if you have enough data in the table, it will most likely change. With the empty table, it hardly matters anyway.